# unmet dependencies while rosdep install openni_launch

Tags: ros, kinect, asus-xtion-pro-live, openni-launch, openni-camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi ,

I am just trying to install openni_launch and openni_camera to get my asus xtion pro live to work.

I have ubuntu 12.04 and fuerte.
when I type

rosdep install openni_camera

sai@sai-HP-EliteBook-8460w:~/fuerte_workspace$ rosdep install openni_camera
executing command [sudo apt-get install libopenni-dev]
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libopenni-dev : Depends: libopenni0 (= 1.5.4.0-4+precise1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
ERROR: the following rosdeps failed to install
apt: command [sudo apt-get install libopenni-dev] failed

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/55173/unmet-dependencies-while-rosdep-install-openni_launch/) by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1935 on 2013-02-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How i solved was,

I removed ps-engine from ubuntu software center and then i was able to do rosdep and install dependencies.

This has occurred because I had pcl libraries installed before and some dependency conflict might have occured

---

Originally posted by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) with karma: 1935 on 2013-02-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0